# Hector_slam and frames ?!!! I'm lost

Tags: slam, navigation, frames, hector-slam, frame-id

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.
I have a wheeled robot that provide odometry, ahrs and a laser.
I'm trying to use hector_slam but I don't understand the frame and transform system.

My base robot package provide an "**/odom**" topic and frame. This frame has the "**/base_link**" frame as child : [driver code](http://roswifibot.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/roswifibot/trunk/src/wifibot.cpp?revision=7&content-type=text%2Fplain)

I set up my launch file as follow :

```
<node pkg="hector_imu_attitude_to_tf" type="imu_attitude_to_tf_node" name="imu_attitude_to_tf_node" output="screen">
  <remap from="imu_topic" to="/imu" />
  <param name="base_stabilized_frame" type="string" value="/base_stabilized" />
  <param name="base_frame" type="string" value="/base_frame" />
</node>

<node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">

  <!-- Frame names -->
  <param name="map_frame" value="/map" />
  <param name="base_frame" value="/base_footprint" />
  <param name="odom_frame" value="/odom" />

  <!-- Tf use -->
  <param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
  <param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>
  <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>

  <!-- Map size / start point -->
  <param name="map_resolution" value="0.050"/>
  <param name="map_size" value="2048"/>
  <param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
  <param name="map_multi_res_levels" value="2" />

  <!-- Map update parameters -->
  <param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
  <param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.9" />
  <param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.4"/>
  <param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
  <param name="laser_z_min_value" value = "-1.0" />
  <param name="laser_z_max_value" value = "1.0" />

  <!-- Advertising config -->
  <param name="advertise_map_service" value="true"/>

  <param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="5"/>
  <param name="scan_topic" value="/laser/scan"/>

  <param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="scanmatcher_frame" />
</node>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_link" args="0.031 0.0 0.251 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser 50" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="imu_link" args="-0.049 0.0 0.180 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /imu 50" />
```

When I launch my launch file I have the following errors :

```
[ INFO] [1341430193.896364275]: lookupTransform /base_footprint to /laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
[ERROR] [1341430193.945936734]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_link failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (9): Frame /base_link exists with parent /odom.
Frame /odom exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /base_frame exists with parent /base_stabilized.
Frame /base_stabilized exists with parent NO_PARENT.
Frame /laser exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /imu exists with parent /base_link.
```

One week I'm trying to understand the frame and transform system without success :/
Is there an exemple that exmplain how to use hector_slam from scratch ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37933/hector_slam-and-frames-?!!!-i%27m-lost.../) by [psykokwak](https://answers.ros.org/users/2765/psykokwak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2012-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
[ INFO] [1341430193.896364275]: lookupTransform /base_footprint to /laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
[ERROR] [1341430193.945936734]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to /base_link failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (9): Frame /base_link exists with parent /odom.
```

This tells you that there is no link between /base_link and /laser and that there is a transform /base_footprint which was not resolveable to /laser. You can solve this by changing

```
<param name="base_frame" value="/base_footprint" />
```

to

```
<param name="base_frame" value="/base_stabilized" />
```

or change your static_tranform_publischers to /base_stabilized .

For more infos check this [How-To-Setup http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot).

---

Originally posted by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) with karma: 663 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-07-04**:
Take a look also at http://answers.ros.org/question/31618/hector-mapping-stabilized-frame/